# Devise is logging out users after a password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and when a user changes a password the site logs them out. I read online that adding the sign_in will do the trick but not working and the user gets logged out when a password change. Here is my code

```
if @user.errors[:base].empty? and @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
  flash[:success] = "User account has been successfully updated"
  redirect_to edit_user_path(params[:site_id], @user)
else
  render :action => :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I was assuming that this would work but regardless of what i do i still get logged out....anything missing or maybe one devise setting is off...any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 13):

I usually folow [these](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) instructions and it works. Maybe you should do

```
sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
```

instead of

```
sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
```