# How do I keep the user signed in after they update their password using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Whenever a user updates their password, it signs the user out and asks them to sign in again. This is my action

`users_controller.rb`

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update user_params
      sign_in @user, bypass: true # for some reason Devise signs the user out
      redirect_to @user
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_in-instance_method

I tried `sign_in @user`, also, but that didn't work. I tried it without `sign_in` but that didn't work either. I saw this answer, but it doesn't help: [Devise is logging out users after a password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567732/devise-is-logging-out-users-after-a-password-change). Updating the user without the password is working OK. (There is some code not shown.)

Devise 3.4.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to add a 'scope`. This worked.

```
sign_in :user, @user, bypass: true # for some reason Devise signs the user out
```

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589286/148844